# Doctrine entity to Json using GetSetMethodNormalizer return fatal error

Tags: json, doctrine-orm, entity

I am using Doctrine 2 and Zend framework since a few days.
I am generating my entities across yaml files.
Now I met an issue to convert my entities Doctrine into Json format (in order to use it through AJAX).

Here is the code used :

```
    $doctrineobject = $this->entityManager->getRepository('\Entity\MasterProduct')->find($this->_request->id);
    $serializer = new \Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer(array(new Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\GetSetMethodNormalizer()), array('json' => new Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder()));

    $reports = $serializer->serialize($doctrineobject, 'json');
```

below is the return I get :

Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in /Users/Sites/library/Symfony/Component/Serializer/Normalizer/GetSetMethodNormalizer.php on line 185

the issue seems to be the same than here :
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.php.symfony.symfony2/2659

but there is not proper solution proposed.

Any idea how can I do it ?

Cheers

Comment: so basically, Symfony doesn't support JSON

Answer (score 4):

I solved the same problem by writing my own GetSetNormalizer my class. Defined static variable in a  class for branching

```
class LimitedRecursiveGetSetMethodNormalizer extends GetSetMethodNormalizer
{ 
public static $limit=2;
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function normalize($object, $format = null)
{
    $reflectionObject = new \ReflectionObject($object);
    $reflectionMethods = $reflectionObject->getMethods(\ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC);

    $attributes = array();
    foreach ($reflectionMethods as $method) {
        if ($this->isGetMethod($method)) {
            $attributeName = strtolower(substr($method->name, 3));
            $attributeValue = $method->invoke($object);
            if (null !== $attributeValue && !is_scalar($attributeValue) && LimitedRecursiveGetSetMethodNormalizer::$limit>0) {
                LimitedRecursiveGetSetMethodNormalizer::$limit--;
                $attributeValue = $this->serializer->normalize($attributeValue, $format);
                LimitedRecursiveGetSetMethodNormalizer::$limit++;
            }

            $attributes[$attributeName] = $attributeValue;
        }
    }

    return $attributes;
}

/**
 * Checks if a method's name is get.* and can be called without parameters.
 *
 * @param ReflectionMethod $method the method to check
 * @return Boolean whether the method is a getter.
 */
private function isGetMethod(\ReflectionMethod $method)
{
    return (
        0 === strpos($method->name, 'get') &&
            3 < strlen($method->name) &&
            0 === $method->getNumberOfRequiredParameters()
    );
  } 
 }
```

And usage

```
    LimitedRecursiveGetSetMethodNormalizer::$limit=3;
    $serializer = new Serializer(array(new LimitedRecursiveGetSetMethodNormalizer()), array('json' => new
    JsonEncoder()));
    $response =new Response($serializer->serialize($YOUR_OBJECT,'json'));
```

Answer (score 1):

[JMSSerializerBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle) seems to handle circular references fine.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look on it.